# Jquery ajax to retrive php get variable

Tags: jquery, action

I would like to take the $id variable from an ajax form (input.php) and make it usable on the main page so I can .submit() the form using this variable in the action='ask.php?q='.

Main Page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#questionSubmit').click(function(){

    $.post("input.php", { question: questionForm.question.value , detail: questionForm.detail.value }, );

});

});

</script>
<form method='POST' action='ask.php?q=<?php echo $id ?>' name='questionForm'>   
        <p>Question:</p>
        <p><input type='text' name='question' id='question'></p>

        <p><textarea id='detail' name='detail'></textarea></p>
        <p>Tags:</p>
        <p><input type='button' value='submit' name='questionSubmit' id='questionSubmit'></p>
    </form>
```

Input.php:

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';
    if (isset($_POST['questionSubmit'])){

    $question=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question']);
    $detail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['detail']);
    $date=date("d M Y");
    $time=time();
    $user=$_SESSION['id'];
    $put=mysql_query("INSERT INTO questions VALUES ('','$question','$detail','$date','$time','$user','subject','0')");

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE user='$user' AND time='$time'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

             $id=$row['id'];

            }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post("input.php", { question: questionForm.question.value , detail: questionForm.detail.value },
   function(data) {
    //add the id to question input, or any other input element you want
     $("#question").val(data);
   });

//and your input.php, echo the $id
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

             $id=$row['id'];

            }
echo $id;
```